# Reading Data Pump Task in DTS without having source and destination environment

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, migration, sql-server-2000, dts

I am working on migrating a DTS package which contains a oledb source (but we dont have access to the source), a olebd destination (but we have access to the dest.) and a DATA Pump Task.

In this situation If i want to migrate it to 2008 task is it possible.

I don't know how the mappings are defined as 2000 designer throws errors saying unable to find source.

Is there way to skip valdiation of Source when opening Data Pump Task, so that i can see  the mappings and define SSIS package.

Please help. its a bit urgent :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you will have to do a lot of clicking to get the column names:
Open the DTS package and in the "package" menu hit the "disconnected edit". There you have to find the specified pump task (under the tasks). There you will have transformations defined (usually each column = 1 transformation) and under each transformation you will have source and destination columns.